# can't set properly a registry key to modify the Explorer left side

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-registry, regedit

I've got this registry key and it actually creates an entry that redirects you to a folder, but I want to open a shortcut instead (.lnk file) and I can't figure it out how to make it working, since now it's broken and can't open the path ('cause it's not a folder but a shortcut).
Please help!
(However I'm on Windows 11)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{0E270DAA-1BE6-48F2-AC49-1BA683D7399C}]
@="Adobe Creative Cloud Files"
"System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree"=dword:00000001
"SortOrderIndex"=dword:00000042

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{0E270DAA-1BE6-48F2-AC49-1BA683D7399C}]
@="Adobe Creative Cloud Files"
"System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree"=dword:00000001
"SortOrderIndex"=dword:00000042

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{0E270DAA-1BE6-48F2-AC49-1BA683D7399C}\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\icons (.ico files)\\Creative Cloud Files.ico,0"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{0E270DAA-1BE6-48F2-AC49-1BA683D7399C}\Instance]
"CLSID"="{0E270DAA-1BE6-48F2-AC49-1BA683D7399C}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{0E270DAA-1BE6-48F2-AC49-1BA683D7399C}\Instance\InitPropertyBag]
"TargetFolderPath"="C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Creative Cloud\\Adobe Creative Cloud Files.lnk"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel]
"{0E270DAA-1BE6-48F2-AC49-1BA683D7399C}"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{0E270DAA-1BE6-48F2-AC49-1BA683D7399C}]
@="Adobe Creative Cloud Files"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{0E270DAA-1BE6-48F2-AC49-1BA683D7399C}\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\icons (.ico files)\\Creative Cloud Files.ico,0"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{0E270DAA-1BE6-48F2-AC49-1BA683D7399C}\Instance\InitPropertyBag]
"TargetFolderPath"="C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Adobe Creative Cloud\\Adobe Creative Cloud Files.lnk"
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has actively removed areas in their programs that you can modify (common news upon the launch of Windows 11).

You cannot do what you want in Windows 11. (It may have been possible in earlier operating systems).

You should endeavor to reverse your changes to ensure Windows 11 is working properly.

Comment: If you know a possible fix, even if it will not work in Windows 11, please write it down here

Comment: Microsoft re-wrote the program code and so things that were done in earlier systems are no longer possible.